# Convert CSV to array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, csv

I have a CSV with each row 2 IPs. I want to combine 2 IPs separated by `***` and populate in an array. I tried the code below, but I only get the last row.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="IPPairs.csv"
array=()

while IFS="," read var1 var2 ; do
        echo $var1 $var2
        pairString="$var1***$var2"
        array+=($pairString)
done < $INPUT

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: Work's fine for me. Are your ip addresses in `IPPairs.csv` comma delimited? Consider tossing some double quotes in there `array+=("$pairString")` for example. But with straight IP addresses, you should be fine. If there are domain names in there with backslashes you may want to use `read -r` to avoid mangling

Answer (score 1):

Unless your input file contains something other than `,` as the delimiter, your code should work. You could make it shorter, though (requires Bash 4.0 or newer):

```
mapfile -t array < IPPairs.csv
array=("${array[@]/,/***}")
```

The first command reads the file into an array, the second command replaces `,` with `***` in each array element.